# Inserting Multiple rows in ASP.NET MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I'm having trouble inserting multiple data on my database.. This is my code below:

Context class:

```
 public void Add(IEnumerable<UserInformation> model)
 {   
        foreach(UserInformation user in model)
        {
            _db.Add(user);
        }

        _db.SaveChanges();                                        
 }
```

This is my controller:

```
[HttpPost]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public async Task<IActionResult> Add(IEnumerable<UserInformation> userInformation)
{
        if (!ModelState.IsValid)
        {
        }   

       _ui_context.Add(userInformation);

        return new JsonResult("User Saved!");
}
```

This is my view:

```
 @model IEnumerable<MyMVC.Models.UserInformation>
 <form method="POST" id="form_data">                                               
                    <input type="hidden" id="action_value" value="" />
                    <table id="tbl_data" class="table table-bordered">
                        <thead>
                            <tr>
                                <th>First Name</th>
                                <th>Last Name</th>
                                <th>Location</th>
                            </tr>
                        </thead>
                        <tbody id="table_data">

                            <tr>
                                <td>
                                    <input  type="hidden" id="txtId" class="form-control" />
                                    <input name="firstname" class="form-control" id="txtFirst" />
                                    <span class="text-danger"></span>
                                </td>
                                <td>
                                    <input name="lastname" class="form-control" id="txtLast" />
                                    <span class="text-danger"></span>
                                </td>
                                <td>
                                    <input  name="location" class="form-control" id="txtLocation" />
                                    <span class="text-danger"></span>
                                </td>
                            </tr>


                        </tbody>                             
                    </table>                                   
                </form>              
                <a class="btn btn-info" id="btnAddField">Click to Add more Fields</a>
```

This is my AJAX:

codes in adding fields

```
//Add fields
        var i = 1;
        $(document).on("click", "#btnAddField", function () {

            $("#table_data").append("<tr>"
                + "<td><input asp-for='FirstName' name='firstname' class='form-control' id='txtFirst" + i + "' />"
                + "<span class='text-danger'></span ></td>"
                + '<td><input asp-for="LastName" name="lastname" class="form-control" id="txtLast' + i + '" />'
                + '<span class="text-danger" ></span ></td>'
                + '<td><input asp-for="Location" name="location" class="form-control" id="txtLocation'+i+'" />'
                + '<span class="text-danger"></span ></td>'
                + "</tr > ");

            i++;
        });
```

codes in POST

```
var data = $('#form_data').serialize();                

                $.ajax({
                    method: "POST",
                    url: "/UserInformation/Add",
                    data: data,
                    dataType: "JSON",
                    success: function (data) {
                        alert(data);
                        clearFields();
                        $("#exampleModal").modal("hide");
                        loadUser();
                    }
                });
```

I'm getting a null response on ajax every time I debugging it. I am very thankful if you would help me with this.

Thank you!

Comment: Is the validation code block really empty? Also: have you checked the data passed to the controller while debugging?

Comment: I just deleted the validation. When I checked the data passed on debug, it shows Count = 0 @DavideVitali

Comment: What is the result of `$('#form_data').serialize();`  Are you getting data in add method of controller? Is there any error in browser console or you checked network tab in browser console?

Comment: I am getting this result when I alert form_data https://i.stack.imgur.com/RHCIw.png @Hardik

Comment: I haven't tried the code, but just by looking at it I don't understand what is `_db.Add(user)`. It is like you are adding a user directly into the context instead of its entity. Shouldn't it read `_db.Users.Add(user)` or something like that?

Comment: Thank you for your opinion @PriyankPanchal, my code is working when i dont use any IEnumerable to my models.

Comment: @PriyankPanchal Ef can infer from the type that you're adding to users with just `_db.Add(entity)` where entity is a `User`. It just doesn't read as nicely if someone named `user` as `obj` or something giving `_db.add(obj)` so `_db.Users.Add()`, I would say is preferred for readability.

Comment: Can any one help me with my problem? thankyou

Comment: @PaulVincentDoroyan How to remove row

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For model binding to work you need to give you fields an index in the name property.
Have a look at this question where I [answered](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55115401/3763021) a very similar question:

So you code needs to look something like the below, but note that using `asp-for` in javascript probably won't work because for that to work the tag helper has to be rendered server side, where you're just attaching html to the dom.

You also need to keep a running total for the index as each `i` needs to be unique for that group of UserInformation.

```
<tr>
    <td>
        <input  type="hidden" id="txtId" class="form-control" />
        <input name="UserInformation[0].firstname" class="form-control" id="txtFirst" />
        <span class="text-danger"></span>
    </td>
    <td>
        <input name="UserInformation[0].lastname" class="form-control" id="txtLast" />
        <span class="text-danger"></span>
    </td>
    <td>
        <input  name="UserInformation[0].location" class="form-control" id="txtLocation" />
        <span class="text-danger"></span>
    </td>
</tr>

//Add fields
var i = 1;
$(document).on("click", "#btnAddField", function () {

    $("#table_data").append("<tr>"
        + "<td><input asp-for='FirstName' name='UserInformation[i].firstname' class='form-control' id='txtFirst" + i + "' />"
        + "<span class='text-danger'></span ></td>"
        + '<td><input asp-for="LastName" name="UserInformation[i].lastname" class="form-control" id="txtLast' + i + '" />'
        + '<span class="text-danger" ></span ></td>'
        + '<td><input asp-for="Location" name="UserInformation[i].location" class="form-control" id="txtLocation'+i+'" />'
        + '<span class="text-danger"></span ></td>'
        + "</tr > ");

    i++;
});
```

Comment: Thankyou very much for your answer @Topher, Do i need to write asp-for in each input tag?

Comment: My pleasure. no, you dont, as I said it won't work in your javascript but it will work and is the preferred way if you're just writing normal html. But I'd say don't use it at all in your situation because it'll only work for the first few fields and then not for the rest so will be weird. What you can do though is render a test asp-for tag somewhere, then study the html it produces and add that to your javascript where you create your elements, or at least view what isn't being rendered by not using asp-for and be that much the wiser.  :)

Comment: Its works! Thank you very much @Topher, u saved my day!

Comment: Great, glad to hear it :)