# Using two models for one view in MVC, one to get data, another one to send data to controller

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core

I know one view can have only one model, so I put these two models in one file SurveyForm. How to get the results, the answered question and send them to the controller?

```
public class SurveyForm
    {
        public List<Question> SurveyQuestions { get; set; }
        public List<Answer> SurveyResults { get; set; }
    }

public class Question
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public int? ParentID { get; set; }
        public string Text { get; set; }        
        public List<Response> Responses { get; set; }
        public List<Question> SubQuestions { get; set; }
        public string RenderType { get; set; }
    }

public class Answer
    {
        public int ResponseID { get; 
        public string Value { get; set; }
    }
```

I render Questions looping through Questions, there are some subQuestions so I have nested loops (three levels of loops). I am able to render these questions, but getting the results is not really easy for me. If I make a SurveyForm model, consisting of List of Questions and Answers, how to set the ResponseID and Value for each Result item inside the list? Using for loop will not work, because there are 20 responses, but 7 questions and 13 subquestions.

Here is a part of the view that I'm rendering:

```
@model MyApp.Models.SurveyForm
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Survey";
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
}

@using (Html.BeginForm("SubmitForm", "Survey"))
{
    int orderNumber = 1;
    foreach (var item in Model.SurveyQuestions)
    {
        <div> @(orderNumber++)) &nbsp; @item.Text </div> //just a title of the question
        if (item.RenderType == "Radiobutton")
        {
            <div>
                @foreach (var subitem in item.Responses)
                {
                    <div>
                        @Html.RadioButton(subitem.QuestionID.ToString(), subitem.ResponseID)
                        @Html.Label(subitem.Text)
                    </div>
                }
            </div>
            <div @Html.TextArea(item.SubQuestions.FirstOrDefault().Answers.FirstOrDefault().ResponseID.ToString(), null, new { @class = "form-control" })</div>
        }

        if (item.RenderType == "Textbox")
        {
            <div>
                @Html.TextArea(item.Id.ToString(), null, new { @class = "form-control" })
            </div>
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Two points here I think:

1. You don't have to use the same model when posting back to the server as you used when setting up the page. i.e, you can pass your view a model of `List<Question>`, which you loop through to build the HTML. And then in your POST Controller method (SubmitForm), can have a signature like the below

Which might help simplify your model objects but isn't necessary.

```
public async Task<IActionResult> SubmitForm(List<Answer> model) 
{

}
```

2.
   In order to bind a list of items in your HTML to an object, you need to give the name property of the html element an 'index' value, that represents the index of the item in the list, after the name of the Object so it will be like 
"Answer[index].ResponseId", where Answer is the name of the Object you're trying to bind to.

Your HTML can be something like this:

```
for(int i =0; i < Model.SurveyQuestions; i++)
{
    var item = Model.SurveyQuestions[i];

if (item.RenderType == "Textbox")
    {
        <div>

            <textarea name="SurveyResults[i].ResponseID" value="@item.Id.ToString()" class = "form-control" >
        </div>
    }
}
```

Have a look at this similar question I [answered previously](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55115401/3763021)

Hope that points you in the right direction.

Comment: THe SurveyResults is inaccessible inside the view. 
 for (int i = 0; i < Model.Count; i++)
        {
            @Html.TextAreaFor(m => m[i].) /// here m is a question object, not a result
        }

Comment: @HomeMade you've tagged asp.net-core, so are you using it? Or is this MVC 5? .net core has replaced the Html helpers with tag helpers. They have different syntax that looks more like normal html and works very similarly to my example. I don't think you can use the standard Html helpers with binding lists because out of the box they don't add indexs to the name property for lists, so I think either way you need to change your Html to not use the tag helpers, then giving it a name like in my example will allow it to bind correctly

Comment: Now that you've mentioned it, it's MVC 5, didn't know those were two separate things.

Comment: @HomeMade, ok, in that case, I don't think you can do it using a kind of default Html helper method. If you need to bind to sub lists then you have to do the naming as I mentioned and do something like `name="SurveyForm.SurveyResults[i].[k].ResonseID`.

You obviously lose the strongly typed side of your Html but unless build some, what I would imagine to be fairly complicated, custom html helpers I don't know of another way.