# Pass table Object from view to controller using asp.net mvc

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I am new to ASP.net MVC still in learning stage :) Thank you Advance

I have created the View Model to populate the table data based on the PName which I have selected.

Ex: for 1 project we have 10 related Items in , i am displaying all the rows on the screen, and making some updates to those rows  to save it back to Database.

I am able to get the data but when I am trying to send the table object to controller to save, it always giving me null

```
Here is my ViewModel

namespace Application.ViewModel.Projects
{
    public class PUpdates
    {
        public List<FItems> items{ get; set; }

    }
}

CSHTML code
@using (Html.BeginForm("PFItems", "Projects", FormMethod.Post))
{
    <table id="test">
        <tr id="testtr">
            <th id="testth"></th>
            <th id="testth"></th>
        </tr>
        @foreach (var item in Model.FItems)
        {
            <tr id="testtr">
                <td id="testtd">
                    @Html.Label(item.Ftype)
                </td>
                <td id="testtd">
                    @Html.TextBox("test", item.AC)
                </td>
            </tr>
        }
        <tr> <td><input type="submit" value="Submit" /></td></tr>

    </table>
}
```

Controller Code

```
   [HttpPost]
    public PartialViewResult PFItems(PFUviewmodel)
    {

        return PartialView(viewmodel);
    }
```

I am not able to get my table Object to make the update

Comment: What version of MVC are you using? You've tagged this with two different versions, as well as the non-specific `asp.net-mvc` tag. Please [edit] your question to remove the version tags if the version doesn't matter, or to limit to the version you are actually using.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Welcome to Stack overflow :)

For model binding to work you need to give you fields an index in the name property. Have a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55115401/3763021) question where I answered a very similar question and explained it.

In your case you need to do something like the following:

```
@model Application.ViewModel.Projects.ProjectfinanceUpdate
@using (Html.BeginForm("PartialprojectFinanceItem", "Projects", FormMethod.Post))
{
    <table id="test">
        <tr id="testtr">
            <th id="testth">Financial Type</th>
            <th id="testth">Actual Cost</th>
        </tr>
        @var i =0;
        @foreach (var item in Model.tblFinanceItems)
        {

            <tr id="testtr">
                <td id="testtd">
                    @Html.Label(item.FinancialType)
                </td>
                <td id="testtd">
                    <input name="ProjectfinanceUpdate.tblFinanceItems[@i].ActualCost" value="@item.ActualCost"/>
                </td>
            </tr>
            @i++;
        }
        <tr> <td><input type="submit" value="Submit" /></td></tr>

    </table>
}
```

The important part is that model binding works off of the name property, and because it's a list, it needs to have an index property.

Hope that helps.

Comment: Thank you So my controller logic will take Array of projectfinanceupdate?

Comment: @Vikasan it shouldn't have to, since your `ProjectfinanceUpdate` has a property which is the list if you look at the html in my answer you'll see I included the `ProjectfinanceUpdate` object in the name. It could also be a list of `List<tblFinancialItem>` if you wanted. In which case you would remove that first object reference in the name.